# Auto run/schedule multiple scripts and (auto) export the outputs into CSV/Excel

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, toad, toad-data-point

Is there a way to execute or schedule multiple scripts in Toad 11g and also export the data into CSV or excel without having to it manually or one script at a time?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be this:

- create a stored procedure (or procedure**s**) which will extract data you need
- that procedure would utilize `UTL_FILE` package
- it means that you'll also need to have a *directory* (Oracle object which points to a directory on database server) and acquire read/write privileges on it
- make sure that procedure returns desired result - don't forget to separate columns by a semi-colon so that such a CSV file is readable by MS Excel
- then create database job (using `DBMS_JOB` (simpler) or `DBMS_SCHEDULER` (more advanced)) which will call that procedure in a scheduled manner (for example, every day at 02:30)
- next morning, pick up created CSV file(s) and do whatever you plan to do with it/them